# Print duplicate lines from text file then delete all but one of the duplicates?

Tags: python, file-io, duplicates

I have a text file with lines of data like the following:

```
data123||data456
data146||data269
data123||data456
data697||data983
data123||data456
```

I want to first print the duplicated lines so that I can keep a record of what these lines are. Then I would like to create a new text file in which I delete all but one copy of those duplicated lines in the original text file.

So far, I have the following code, but it seems to give me duplicated individual "data###" rather than the entire LINE that it contains in.

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    seen = set ()
    for line in f:
            line_lower =line.lower()
            if line_lower in seen:
                print (line)
            else:
                seen.add(line_lower)
```

Comment: work fine for me when I use your code. can you add the bad output you get with that example?. In addition, I would strip the line to ignore newlines, like here: `line_lower =line.lower().strip()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a set:

```
s=set()
for line in open("file.txt"):
    if line in s:
        print line
    else:
        s.add(line)
```

Then rewrite the file:

```
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in s:
        f.write(line)
```

Comment: Just one remark, that this solution does not guarantee preserving order

Answer (score 0):

Printing lines as they are is no rocket science, so I focus on removing duplicates while saving order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = """data123||data456
data146||data269
data123||data456
data697||data983
data123||data456"""

uniq = OrderedDict((row, None) for row in data.splitlines()).keys()
```

The result in `uniq` is list of lines without duplicates:

```
In [10]: print '\n'.join(uniq)
  data123||data456
  data146||data269
  data697||data983
```